# add text in all of the rows

Tags: linux, bash, scripting

I am working in a linux environment and I would like to get some help on bash scripting to cut down on simple repetition.

I have long list of file names(937 to be exact). In that file on one row there is only one file name there, therefore, total of 937 lines in the file.

I would like to add certain text before the file name and add numbers after the file name in order.

so I would like something like this in the text file.

```
aa.exe

bb.exe

cc.exe
```

to

```
asd aa.exe 1

asd bb.exe 2

asd cc.exe 3
```

any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are the file names in a simple .txt file? Are you looking to use a certain language, or regular expressions? Specific software or technology???

Comment: I am working in a linux bash environment.

Answer (score 5):

Just for kicks, here's an awk version:

```
awk '{print "foo", $0, NR}' files.lst
```

If `files.lst` consists of:

```
a.txt
b.txt
c.txt
```

...then this will output:

```
foo a.txt 1
foo b.txt 2
foo c.txt 3
```

Comment: ha ha .. that's a good one (I'm a big fan of `awk`, strange I didn't think of it). Python is more fun though :)

Comment: @Levon: There are indeed many ways to solve this problem.  ;)

Answer (score 2):

Pure Bash:

```
while read -r line
do
    echo "asd $line $((++i))"
done < inputfile
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple Python solution, save it in a text file named `so.py`. 
Since you are still using Python v 2.4.2, this code should work with that earlier version:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

add_text = 'asd'  # the string to put in front

fn  = open('filenames.txt')
outf =  open('outdata.txt', 'w')

i = 1
for filename in fn:
    outf.write('%7s %10s %d\n' % (add_text, filename.strip(), i))
    i += 1

fn.close()
outf.close()
```

Expects the names of the files to be in file `filenames.txt`, and the output generated goes to file `outdata.txt`.

```
asd    aa.exe    1
asd    bb.exe    2
asd    cc.exe    3
```

The text to be added ahead of the filename is fixed in the variable `add_text`.

To run the script, issue these commands at the Linux prompt:

```
chmod +x so.py    <-- this is only needed once
./so.py           <-- to run the script
```

and it will use the input file to generate the output file.

Comment: seems like I cannot use python. It gives me command not found on the add_text command.

Comment: I have python 2.4.2 and I am getting syntaxerror: invalid syntax on line 5 with open('filename.txt') as fn:

Comment: @doyongkim Wow .. that's pretty old :-) Give me 5 minutes and I'll update it, it's trivial.

Comment: @doyongkim What I just put there should work, I got rid of enumerate. You may want to consider upgrading Python at some point. 2.6 is pretty standard for most Linux version and works quite well. v3.2.3 is the most current version.

Comment: enumerate is giving problems, typeerror: enermerate () takes exactly 1 argument 2 given at line 8

Comment: I will ask the admin of the cluster to update the scripts when she can.

Answer (score 0):

In vim:

```
:%s/.\+/\=printf("%s %s %d", "asdf", submatch(0), line("."))/
```

Comment: Yes - a command starting with a ':' means it is to be run from the vim command line.